# Coloured background using geom_rect

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to color the background of a line plot (geom_line) based on different factors. In this example, I highlight the background of a time series plot based on the 4 seasons of the year.

I specify the position of the rectangles for the different seasons, however I cannot specify the fill color. I indicate the colors for each season, but the plot contains different colors to the ones selected by me.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

```
# Create a dataset
Iteration <- seq (1:24)
Values <- runif (24, 0, 1)
Season <- rep (c( rep("winter", 3), rep ("Summer", 3), rep ("Autumn", 3), rep ("Winter", 3)),2)
df <- data.frame (Iteration, Values, Season) ; df

# Indicate the seasons in the X axis
start_spring <- which(Season == "Spring") ; end_spring <- start_spring + 1
start_summer <- which(Season == "Summer") ; end_summer <- start_summer + 1
start_autumn <- which(Season == "Autumn") ; end_autumn <- start_autumn + 1
start_winter <- which(Season == "Winter") ; end_winter <- start_winter + 1

# Indicate the size (y axis) of the rectangle
ymin_season <- rep(0, 24)
ymax_season <- rep(1, 24)

# Create a dataframe for indicating the position of the rectangles
shade <- data.frame (start_spring, end_spring, 
                     start_summer, end_summer, 
                     start_autumn, end_autumn, 
                     start_winter, end_winter, 
                     ymin_season, ymax_season)

# Plot
ggplot (df) +
  geom_line(aes(x=Iteration, y=Values)) + 
  geom_rect (data=shade, aes(xmin=start_spring, xmax=end_spring, ymin=ymin_season, ymax=ymax_season, fill="green"), alpha=0.05) +
  geom_rect (data=shade, aes(xmin=start_summer, xmax=end_summer, ymin=ymin_season, ymax=ymax_season, fill="red"), alpha=0.05) +
  geom_rect (data=shade, aes(xmin=start_autumn, xmax=end_autumn, ymin=ymin_season, ymax=ymax_season, fill="brown"), alpha=0.05) +
  geom_rect (data=shade, aes(xmin=start_winter, xmax=end_winter, ymin=ymin_season, ymax=ymax_season, fill="blue"), alpha=0.05)
```

Comment: I think `fill` needs to go outside of `aes()`

Comment: Yes it was problem. Thanks. I put the solution for helping people: `ggplot (df) +
  geom_line(aes(x=Iteration, y=Values)) + 
  geom_rect (data=shade, aes(xmin=start_spring, xmax=end_spring, ymin=ymin_season, ymax=ymax_season), fill="green", alpha=0.05)`